# cURL, script returning 503 Error (service unavailable)

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to login on the page 'http://portal.demo.ascio.com/Logon.aspx' with cURL but i am getting this error "503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request. ".
I am sending right POST which i get from firebug by login to the normal page.
I have been searching for a while and figured out that maybe i am not sending right header.

Code is:

```
$url = 'http://portal.demo.ascio.com/Logon.aspx';

$login_string = 'THERE ARE MY POSTS WHICH CONTAINS PASSWORD...thats is definitelly right'
$headers = array();                                                                                                            
$headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";                                         
$headers[] = "Host: portal.demo.ascio.com";                                    
$headers[] = "Referer: http://portal.demo.ascio.com/Logon.aspx";               
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";                                 
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";                                
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                

//open connection                                                                                                              
$ch = curl_init();                                                                                                             

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);                                        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');                             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                                           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 5);                                              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_string);                             

$result = curl_exec($ch);                                                                                                      

print $result;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

curl_close($ch);
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you get the error of 500 series, such as 503, it means your request made it to the server side, and something in your input has caused the server to "break", maybe by design of the server itself. Double-check what you are sending and maybe also compare against the service API/Specs.